# TeamCity - get running builds with build parameters

Tags: teamcity

I want to get the build parameters of a running build, how can i do that via rest?

I know the following link gets me the current running builds

but how can i get the build parameters for them?

```
> http://teamcityserver/httpAuth/app/rest/builds?locator=running:true
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you have the list of running builds you will need to make a call to the URL shown below for each build supplying the relevant ID.

```
http://teamcityserver/httpAuth/app/rest/builds/id:<BuildIdGoesHere>
```

This will retrieve the details of the build including the build parameters which you will find in the `<properties>` node.